# unable to import a csv file which contains empty spaces in its records into Neo4j graph databases

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am trying to create a graph by importing csv file to neo4j,but my records contains some empty spaces ,so neo4j not allowing to create a node

I am unable to replace empty space with anything other in graph databases
my code

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://s3.amazonaws.com/xyz/test.csv" AS db

merge (dbn:dbname {name: db.origin })
merge (dbs:dbschema {name: db.dest})
merge (dbo:dbobj {name: db.via})


create (dbn)-[:via]->(dbs)-[:to]->(dbo)
return dbn,dbs,dbo
```

the csv file data is something  like this,

origin dest   via

```
ny     hk      la
ny     moscow  ft
ny     london
ny     mumbai  dubai
```

now from ny to london is direct so no "via"

but when I create nodes I need a node for empty node let it be with name null

Comment: Your query and CSV example don't belong together? Would help to post the real query and real data..

Comment: done with the changes you suggested,earlier I kept different query and csv for security

Comment: In a graph, an empty `Via` node doesn't make much sense. I would split the data set and create `to` relationships from `dbn` to `dbo` id there is no stop in between.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could ignore the lines where the via column has not value?

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://s3.amazonaws.com/xyz/test.csv" AS db
WITH db
WHERE db.via IS NOT NULL
merge (dbn:dbname {name: db.referencing_DB_Name })
merge (dbs:dbschema {name: db.referencing_schema})
merge (dbo:dbobj {name: db.referencing_object_name})
merge (dbd:dbrdb {name: db.referenced_database})
merge (dbrs:dbrdsch {name: db.referenced_schema})
merge (dbro:dbrdobj {name: db.referenced_object_name})

create (dbn)-[:referencing_schema]->(dbs)-[:referencing_object_name]->(dbo)-[:referenced_database]->(dbd)-[:referenced_schema]->(dbrs)-[:referenced_object_name]->(dbro)
return dbn,dbs,dbo,dbd,dbrs,dbro
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer,it is working but it is deleting the whole row where a empty space is present,but I need that row also,just I need to place something like "emptyData" as node name

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [coalesce() function](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#functions-coalesce) to deal with null values in the csv. Coalesce evaluates to the first non-null argument passed to it, so if you want to use "emptyData" for the `name` property of the `DBObj` node when it does not appear in the csv file just do something like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "http://some.url.com/file.csv" AS row
MERGE (dbn:DBName {name: row.origin })
MERGE (dbs:DBSchema {name: row.dest})
MERGE (dbo:DBObj {name: coalesce(row.via, "emptyData")})
CREATE (dbn)-[:via]->(dbs)-[:to]->(dbo)
return dbn,dbs,dbo
```